# Converting React-Native-Draggable-View from Class to Hooks

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, expo, navigation-drawer

I am attempting to write some code using React-Native-Draggable-View but the example that has it the way I want is written in "class" form, while I write everything in "Hooks/Functional" form. Here is the original part of the code written in the class format. When I try to convert it myself I am generate an error.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component }from "react";
import Drawer from 'react-native-draggable-view'
import CheckScreen from './CheckScreen'
import ListScreen from './ListScreen'

function RunningScreen({navigation}) {

...

return(

...


<Drawer
    initialDrawerSize={0.09}
    renderContainerView={() => { <View style = {{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}/> }}
    renderDrawerView={() => { <View style = {{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}/> }}
    renderInitDrawerView={() => {
      <View style = {{backgroundColor: '#fff', height: height*0.2}}>
        <StatusBar hidden = {true}/>
  <StatusBar hidden = {true}/>
                
    </View>
   )}
  />
    )
    }

...

export {RunningScreen}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
import React from 'react';
import {Dimensions, StatusBar, View} from 'react-native';
import Drawer from 'react-native-draggable-view';

const {height} = Dimensions.get('window');

function RunningScreen({navigation}) {
  return (
    <Drawer
      initialDrawerSize={0.09}
      renderContainerView={() => (
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
      )}
      renderDrawerView={() => (
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
      )}
      renderInitDrawerView={() => (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', height: height * 0.2}}>
          <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        </View>
      )}
    />
  );
}

export {RunningScreen};
```

Comment: So I had actually tried that before. I get an error: "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built in components) or a class/function {for composite components) but got: undefined.....

Check render method of 'component'

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: @MK_Pierce the above updated code works for for me. Please make sure you have `CheckScreen` and `ListScreen` correct path and working code.

Comment: Sure! correct path means "The path of CheckScreen and ListScreen" is properly accessible. Just to make sure. I believe you would have already managed so you can ignore it :)

Comment: I am still getting the same error... I have no clue why. The "renderContainerView" is the file that contains the screen, correct? Also, anything that says "render" screams "class" to me. Is it possible I need to reformat it for hooks?

Comment: Try simple code in "renderContainerView"  and "renderDrawerView"  like `<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red"}} />` to validate there is no issue in the `Drawer` component.

Comment: My bad, Please update `export default function DraggableDrawbaleScreen({navigation})` function name. That will surely help.

Comment: I appreciate your continued support with this issue, but I am still having trouble. The only file I have "export default function" in is my App.js file. I have updated my original post with what I have now; hopefully this will help better address where I am at. The error is the same as the beginning.

Comment: You must change the `CheckScreen` function name or  import `CheckScreen`. They both conflicts here and are not working if name is same for both.
As you can see this `export {CheckScreen}` code is for import `CheckScreen` or function `CheckScreen` is not clear.

Comment: Completely my mistake, I have misnamed the function. I have adjusted it accordingly. The setup is right on my end, I just wrote it here wrong, My apologies.

Comment: However, I am still receiving the same error

Comment: I have updated the code. please see above. 
you should import as I did like this `import {RunningScreen} from '<path of the screen>';`.
It is working at my side

Comment: This is working. Now how do I generate the screens in my drawer?

Comment: I figured the rest out. Thank you so so much for your continued support

Comment: Did you get an error that says "useNativeDriver" must be true or false?

Comment: I did not get the chance to look into it. But It's good to use `useNativeDriver` if possible

Comment: How would I implement it in the code properly? I don't have an animator anywhere in the code.

Comment: This is from `react-native-draggable-view`  in `startAnimation` method. thi chunk of code having issue 
```Animated.timing(position, { toValue: endPosition, tension: 30, friction: 0, // easing:Easing.elastic, velocity: velocityY }).start();```.
I am not sure, how to solve it because it is inside npm module what you have used.